# Perl smtp server for modify and forward message

Tags: perl, smtp, message, forward

I need to create a perl script that works as an smtp server. When it listens an email, it should change its body and then resend it to some other email server (a MS Exchange one)

Is there a simple way to do this? Which perl modules should I use?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following modules to accomplish your task.

**Net::Server::Mail** to recieve mails, check out `DATA` callback as place where you can process recieved e-mail. Then you possibly should mix it with some SMTP client module (such as **Email::Sender**) to send mails.

Maybe you choose to go async way and try **AnyEvent::SMTP**, which combines server and client in single module.